# How to join column with match punctuation to dataframe?

Tags: pandas, nltk

I have a dataframe with contents:

```
    comment
0   'Dah ko mentekedarah duit Rakyat' , nak buat b...
1   Pulang kat sape ha??yg meniaga kcil2 bnyk klua...
2   Xbrbaloi kerajaan pulangkn.semua naik bodoh!!!...
3   oiii kerjaan bn ko org sdr x dh lh kerajaan xd...
4   Tag line pr“kami mendengar denyut nadi rakyat”...
```

I want to find only match punctuation of !, ?, " , ' and return the result to new column, join at the end of original column, with return NaN if not matching:

```
matchedpunct
' '
? ?
! ! !
NaN
“ ”
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.comment.str.extractall(r'([”?!\'])') \
  .groupby(level=0)[0].apply(tuple).str.join(' ')
```

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared. It works but only show the column with match string. But no NaN if not match.